# How to enter commands in the debugger of Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout, xamarin-studio

I want to enter the following command into the debugger

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

How would I do that in Xamarin Studio?

**Edit:**

I saw this Objective-C code

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]);
```

in [programatically change autolayout on orientation change](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/109628-programatically-change-autolayout-on-orientation-change.html) together with an interface definition for that.

```
// for debugging auto layout.
@interface UIWindow (AutoLayoutDebug)
+(UIWindow *)keyWindow;
-(NSString *)_autolayoutTrace;
@end
```

I'd like to know how this can be done in Xamarin iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

var str = new NSString (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Handle, new Selector ("_autolayoutTrace").Handle));
```

And "str" will contain the string that you can then use with Console.WriteLine

Comment: What is `window`? I get a result if I use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Handle`. But I don't see an ambigous layout or something similar, only a trace of all UI objects. `View.Window.Handle` seems to do the same. Is this the expected output of the `AutoLayoutTrace`? Perhaps I don't see it because the system has already resolved the constraints. Do I need something like pause?

Comment: Seems that [*ObjCRuntime.Messaging namespace has been made internal*](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/76739/#Comment_76739) and you can't use this for the unified API.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the unified API the solution posted by [miguel.de.icaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/miguel-de-icaza) doesn't work anymore, because you get

> `ObjCRuntime.Messaging' is inaccessible due to its protection level

One has to use [P/Invoke](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using ObjCRuntime;

public static class UIViewAutolayoutTraceExtensions
{
    [DllImport(Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint="objc_msgSend")]
    private static extern IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector);

    public static NSString AutoLayoutTrace(){
        return (NSString)Runtime.GetNSObject(IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Handle, new Selector ("_autolayoutTrace").Handle));
    }

    public static NSString RecursiveDescription(){
        return (NSString)Runtime.GetNSObject(IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Handle, new Selector ("recursiveDescription").Handle));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(UIViewAutolayoutTraceExtensions.RecursiveDescription ());
```

One caveat though: You can only call this code after everything has been loaded. Otherwise `KeyWindow` will be null. So there is no possibility to set a breakpoint and then call this code. You can only call this code if you provide a button or something similar with which you trigger the action.